# IBM Cognos Business Intelligence 10.2.2 on WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.29 fails to start, possibly due to a missing classpath entry

Tags: java, aix, websphere, db2, cognos

I have a server running IBM AIX 6.1.7.15 TL07 and I am trying to install Cognos Business Intelligence 10.2.2 on WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment 7.0.0.29, using a server cluster to deploy and manage my application and using an IBM DB2 10.5 server to save my content store. When I start one of my cluster's application servers I get the following error message when I try to load my dispatcher URL:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [com.cognos.pogo.isolation.ServletWrapper]: Could not find required class - class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cognos.pogo.isolation.ServletWrapper
```

Checking the WAS log file `SystemOut.log` I found the following error message...

```
Servlet cfgss is currently unavailable: SRVE0200E: Servlet[com.cognos.pogo.isolation.ServletWrapper]: Could not find required class -com.cognos.pogo.isolation.ServletWrapper
```

...which brought me to this [IBM tech note](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21342198) that mentions it could be a problem with a missing CLASSPATH entry on my WAS server's environment variables.

However, the note says nothing about how to fix this issue, and I have absolutely zero idea of what should I put on my CLASSPATH entry. An [IBM Knowledge Center entry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.c8bizos_ig.10.2.1.doc/t_zos_createashellprofile.html) says I should put entries pointing at my DB2 database driver but I very much don't think this is a DB2 driver issue as I can connect perfectly fine to my database from Cognos Configuration and the driver is present on `<Cognos WebSphere application directory>/p2pd.war/WEB-INF/lib/db2jcc.jar`.

Any idea on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, posting here for reference:

The problem was that the nodeagent's configuration on my individual server was outdated respect to the one on my cluster's deployment manager, and as a result my server was apparently starting with an incorrect CLASSPATH.

The solution was to stop the nodeagent and force a full configuration resync from the server's command line using `<WebSphere profile root>/bin/syncNode.sh <Dmgr server IP> <Dmgr SOAP connector port> -restart`. Cognos started normally after resyncing the nodeagent's configuration.